# how to do 3D stable stacking for rigid body in Python

Tags: python, simulation, physics-engine

Is there any library that I can use to do simple 3D stacking simulation in python?
To simplify the issue, all objects are box with integer width / height / depth / top / left / z-index.
And the only thing need to be simulate is determine the stacking is stable or not.

I am currently searching some physical engine to do this job.

vpython
http://vpython.org/contents/doc.html

box2d
http://box2d.org/about/ 
It does stable stacking well, except it is 2d.

An stable stacking sample From box2d
[image]

## EDIT1

I finally end up with using Chrono:PyEngine. It is really easy to use and the python binding is up to date. The only thing hard I found is that the latest version only support python 3.X 
http://www.projectchrono.org/mediawiki/index.php/ChronoPyEngine:Introduction

## EDIT2

My Sample code to run stack checking with Chrono:PyEngine.
https://github.com/lucemia/box/blob/master/physical.py

Comment: If all you need is to determine whether a stacking of axis-aligned boxes is stable, a physics library is overkill, and will probably not be very robust anyway.

Comment: It don't need to be very robust! Just don't want to reinvent the wheel!

Comment: Not all wheels are made equal :) But seriously, 3D physics engines are very complex and full of nasty problems like numerical issues and simulation inaccuracies. My advice remains "don't".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those questions with no really satisfying answer. But take a look at these:

- https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-physicsengines/.
- pyODE (ODE exported to python), but latest is from 2010 and supports up to python 2.6; the C++ side seems to be actively maintained
- newton which has python bindings but latest release (even C++ backend) again not updated since 4/2011;
- bullet which is actively maintained at the C++ level but the python bindings have not been updated in about a year and down't know how comprehensive and stable
- reactphysics3d is C++ but actively maintained: need to create python bindings
- havoc: not free and no python bindings, but appears most powerful

If you are willing to learn SWIG (www.swig.org) you can probably create your own Python binding for the parts of Bullet or PyODE or reactphysics3d that you want. Don't know about Havoc.